# Cцепка столбцов excel

Tags: excel

Есть три столбца , нужно в новом (итог) сцепить значения из трёх остальных .
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое в данном случае "объединить"? сложение? конкатенация? что-то ещё?

Comment: К сожалению, я не знаю каким словом описать взятие данных из 3х столбцов и слепки их воедино :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в ячейке D2 вводишь символ =
мышкой нажимаешь на ячейку A2
нажимаешь на клавиатуре символ +
мышкой нажимаешь на ячейку B2
нажимаешь на клавиатуре символ +
мышкой нажимаешь на ячейку C2
нажимаешь на клавиатуре клавишу Enter
копируешь ячейку D2 во все нижележащие

Comment: Огромное спасибо !

Comment: @АрсенийКоролев если помогло, отметь как решение.